# Adding a pattern from a list in .gitignore

Tags: git, gitignore

I need to ignore these three files:

```
boot.dev.tpl
boot.tst.tpl
boot.prd.tpl
```

Is there a way to add that to `.gitignore` in one line, something like:

`boot.[dev|tst|prd].tpl # This doesn't work`

Comment: Try `boot.[...].tpl`

Comment: `.gitignore` syntax is basically shell glob, with `**` modeled after bash-style `**`, plus the leading `!` for negation, plus leading slash for anchoring, plus optional trailing slash for directory-only matching. So there's no regex style alternation option.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [`.gitignore` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore), there is no facility for matching multiple multi-character sequences in a pattern.

The best solution for your situation is to list each file on its own line.

Answer (score 0):

.gitignore doesn't support regex, only pattern globbing and negation. If you just want to ignore the files, you can accomplish it in a single line with `/boot.*.tpl`, assuming your files and .gitignore are at the toplevel of your git repository. But if they're nested in subdirectories you could do `**/boot.*.tpl`.